# Displaying an object with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have some JSON that looks like this. I have it stored and read into an object, @items.

```
[
 {
  {
    "id": "A",
    "description": "a_description"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "B",
    "description": "b_description"
  }
 }, 
 {
  {
    "id": "A",
    "description": "a_description"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "B",
    "description": "b_description"
  }
 }
]
```

My goal is to display a table with two columns, one labeled A and the other labeled B, in which each row gives the "a_description" and "b_description". I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: +1 for your username. And i didnt understand your question. Is the items array populated with this json? Or you have a json and you want to populate the items array?

Comment: I have the json in a file. From what I understand, when I read in the JSON, I get the items array.

Comment: It looks like the first sublevel beneath the overall array should also be an array [] not a hash {} right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the ol' array of hashes and hashes of arrays problem.

To get around your "out of order" problem you first have to convert

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "description": "foo"
},
{
  "id": "B",
  "description": "bar"
}
```

into `{"A" : "foo", "B" : "bar" }`.

```
@new_items = @items.map do |item|
  output = {}
  item.each do |hash|
    output.merge!(hash["id"] => hash["description"])
  end
end
```

Then `@new_items` becomes (intentionally presented out of order since hash elements are not ordered)

```
[
  { 
    "A": "a1_description",
    "B": "b1_description"
  },
  { 
    "B": "b2_description",
    "A": "a2_description"
  }
]
```

From there, each line is simply a hash, so you can just dereference the value  you need based on the column you're in.

```
@new_items.each do |item|
  puts "#{item['A']} is paired with #{item['B']}"
end
```

Keys, of course could be retrieved dynamically if you don't want to hard code "A" and "B" using `.keys`

Comment: I like this solution, but what if items have a third id, "C" ?

Comment: Is it a known third id, or will it be dynamic or arbitrary?  I kind of hinted at that with the last line, using the .keys method.  You can similarly just get an array of all the values (out of order, since it's a hash) using the .values method.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe

```
<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr><td><%=item[0].description%></td><td><%=item[1].description%></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This would work, but it seems like it's possible for the array items to get out of order- I need to check the id, or it's possible that I'll get items in the wrong columns.

Comment: Yes- that's the exact problem with this solution- none of the items match up with the column their supposed to, and it's not consistent which column they end up in.

Comment: @rapidash, if this is the case.  You will need to parse the data the way you want it to be arranged.  Just loop through the items and restructure it the way you like before displaying.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without individually hardcoding ids for each column? I'd prefer it if I could just generate columns based on what's available.